# Is there any way to link a existed object file in Makefile when compiling?

Tags: c, makefile, linker

I want to use the object files already compiled and only link it in Makefile without compiling again.

Then I can put .o file in source folder not .c file.

Is that possible? Thanks in advance!!

I have tried below, but it is not working.

[How to create reference to an .o file in Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338028/how-to-create-reference-to-an-o-file-in-makefile)

Actually, I still not sure how it works on my case.

More specific:
Please see my makefile:

```
    obj-$(CONFIG_SH_MMCIF) += sh_mmcif.o
    obj-$(CONFIG_SH_SDHI) += sh_sdhi.o
    obj-$(CONFIG_STM32_SDMMC2) += stm32_sdmmc2.o
    obj-$(CONFIG_MMC_NDS32) += nds32_mmc.o
    PREBUILT_O = mysource.o
    obj-$(CONFIG_xxx) += $(PREBUILT_O)
    obj-$(CONFIG_MMC_MXC)           += mxcmmc.o
    obj-$(CONFIG_MMC_MXS)           += mxsmmc.o
```

By the way, I can not find "TARGET" in Makefile.

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) $(PREBUILT_O)

  $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(PREBUILT_O) $(LIBS) -o $@
```

I have no idea how "obj-$() += " works for the final TARGET.

It is hard to find the TARGET in the Makefile of upper folder either.

So here are my steps:

1. Set obj-$(CONFIG_xxx) += mysource.o in Makefile
2. Compile it, it will generate .o file under out/
3. Get mysource.o from out/
4. Remove mysource.c
5. Modify Makefile => link mysource.o to obj-$(CONFIG_xxx) without compiling
6. Compile it

=>The compiling error is occurred. 
Undefined reference function is still there if other .c file use this obj file.

It seems the compiler still compile mysource.o.

How to link mysource.o to obj-$(CONFIG_xxx) without compile again?

By the way, mysource.c and Makefile is under uboot_xxx/drivers/usb/gadget/

Below is part of Makefile under uboot_xxx/

```
ifeq ($(KBUILD_SRC),)
        # building in the source tree
        srctree := .
else
        ifeq ($(KBUILD_SRC)/,$(dir $(CURDIR)))
                # building in a subdirectory of the source tree
                srctree := ..
        else
                srctree := $(KBUILD_SRC)
        endif
endif
objtree     := .
src     := $(srctree)
obj     := $(objtree)

VPATH       := $(srctree)$(if $(KBUILD_EXTMOD),:$(KBUILD_EXTMOD))

export srctree objtree VPATH
############################################
# set default to nothing for native builds
ifeq ($(HOSTARCH),$(ARCH))
CROSS_COMPILE ?=
endif

KCONFIG_CONFIG  ?= .config
export KCONFIG_CONFIG

# SHELL used by kbuild
CONFIG_SHELL := $(shell if [ -x "$$BASH" ]; then echo $$BASH; \
      else if [ -x /bin/bash ]; then echo /bin/bash; \
      else echo sh; fi ; fi)

HOSTCC       = cc
HOSTCXX      = c++
HOSTCFLAGS   = -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer \
        $(if $(CONFIG_TOOLS_DEBUG),-g)
HOSTCXXFLAGS = -O2

ifeq ($(HOSTOS),cygwin)
HOSTCFLAGS  += -ansi
endif

# ======================================================================
# Build targets only - this includes vmlinux, arch specific targets, clean
# targets and others. In general all targets except *config targets.

# Additional helpers built in scripts/
# Carefully list dependencies so we do not try to build scripts twice
# in parallel
PHONY += scripts
scripts: scripts_basic include/config/auto.conf
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=$(@)

# Read in dependencies to all Kconfig* files, make sure to run
# oldconfig if changes are detected.
-include include/config/auto.conf.cmd


u-boot.cfg spl/u-boot.cfg tpl/u-boot.cfg: include/config.h FORCE
    $(Q)$(MAKE) -f $(srctree)/scripts/Makefile.autoconf $(@)

-include include/autoconf.mk
-include include/autoconf.mk.dep

# If board code explicitly specified LDSCRIPT or CONFIG_SYS_LDSCRIPT, use
# that (or fail if absent).  Otherwise, search for a linker script in a
# standard location.

ifndef LDSCRIPT
    #LDSCRIPT := $(srctree)/board/$(BOARDDIR)/u-boot.lds.debug
    ifdef CONFIG_SYS_LDSCRIPT
        # need to strip off double quotes
        LDSCRIPT := $(srctree)/$(CONFIG_SYS_LDSCRIPT:"%"=%)
    endif
endif

# If there is no specified link script, we look in a number of places for it
ifndef LDSCRIPT
    ifeq ($(wildcard $(LDSCRIPT)),)
        LDSCRIPT := $(srctree)/board/$(BOARDDIR)/u-boot.lds
    endif
    ifeq ($(wildcard $(LDSCRIPT)),)
        LDSCRIPT := $(srctree)/$(CPUDIR)/u-boot.lds
    endif
    ifeq ($(wildcard $(LDSCRIPT)),)
        LDSCRIPT := $(srctree)/arch/$(ARCH)/cpu/u-boot.lds
    endif
endif

else

# Add user supplied CPPFLAGS, AFLAGS and CFLAGS as the last assignments
KBUILD_CPPFLAGS += $(KCPPFLAGS)
KBUILD_AFLAGS += $(KAFLAGS)
KBUILD_CFLAGS += $(KCFLAGS)

# Use UBOOTINCLUDE when you must reference the include/ directory.
# Needed to be compatible with the O= option
UBOOTINCLUDE    := \
        -Iinclude \
        $(if $(KBUILD_SRC), -I$(srctree)/include) \
        $(if $(CONFIG_$(SPL_)SYS_THUMB_BUILD), \
            $(if $(CONFIG_HAS_THUMB2),, \
                -I$(srctree)/arch/$(ARCH)/thumb1/include),) \
        -I$(srctree)/arch/$(ARCH)/include \
        -include $(srctree)/include/linux/kconfig.h

NOSTDINC_FLAGS += -nostdinc -isystem $(shell $(CC) -print-file-name=include)
CHECKFLAGS     += $(NOSTDINC_FLAGS)

# FIX ME
cpp_flags := $(KBUILD_CPPFLAGS) $(PLATFORM_CPPFLAGS) $(UBOOTINCLUDE) \
                            $(NOSTDINC_FLAGS)
c_flags := $(KBUILD_CFLAGS) $(cpp_flags)

#########################################################################
# U-Boot objects....order is important (i.e. start must be first)

HAVE_VENDOR_COMMON_LIB = $(if $(wildcard $(srctree)/board/$(VENDOR)/common/Makefile),y,n)
libs-y += lib/
libs-$(HAVE_VENDOR_COMMON_LIB) += board/$(VENDOR)/common/
libs-$(CONFIG_OF_EMBED) += dts/
libs-y += fs/
libs-y += net/
libs-y += disk/
libs-y += drivers/
libs-y += drivers/dma/
libs-y += drivers/gpio/
libs-y += drivers/i2c/
libs-y += drivers/mtd/
libs-$(CONFIG_CMD_NAND) += drivers/mtd/nand/
libs-y += drivers/mtd/onenand/
libs-$(CONFIG_CMD_UBI) += drivers/mtd/ubi/
libs-y += drivers/mtd/spi/
libs-y += drivers/net/
libs-y += drivers/net/phy/
libs-y += drivers/pci/
libs-y += drivers/power/ \
    drivers/power/domain/ \
    drivers/power/fuel_gauge/ \
    drivers/power/mfd/ \
    drivers/power/pmic/ \
    drivers/power/battery/ \
    drivers/power/regulator/
libs-y += drivers/spi/
libs-$(CONFIG_FMAN_ENET) += drivers/net/fm/
libs-$(CONFIG_SYS_FSL_DDR) += drivers/ddr/fsl/
libs-$(CONFIG_SYS_FSL_MMDC) += drivers/ddr/fsl/
libs-$(CONFIG_ALTERA_SDRAM) += drivers/ddr/altera/
libs-y += drivers/serial/
libs-y += drivers/usb/cdns3/
libs-y += drivers/usb/dwc3/
libs-y += drivers/usb/common/
libs-y += drivers/usb/emul/
libs-y += drivers/usb/eth/
libs-y += drivers/usb/gadget/
libs-y += drivers/usb/gadget/udc/
libs-y += drivers/usb/host/
libs-y += drivers/usb/musb/
libs-y += drivers/usb/musb-new/
libs-y += drivers/usb/phy/
libs-y += drivers/usb/ulpi/
libs-y += cmd/
libs-y += common/
libs-y += env/
libs-$(CONFIG_API) += api/
libs-$(CONFIG_HAS_POST) += post/
libs-y += test/
libs-y += test/dm/
libs-$(CONFIG_UT_ENV) += test/env/
libs-$(CONFIG_UT_OVERLAY) += test/overlay/

libs-y += $(if $(BOARDDIR),board/$(BOARDDIR)/)

libs-y := $(sort $(libs-y))

u-boot-dirs := $(patsubst %/,%,$(filter %/, $(libs-y))) tools examples

u-boot-alldirs  := $(sort $(u-boot-dirs) $(patsubst %/,%,$(filter %/, $(libs-))))

libs-y      := $(patsubst %/, %/built-in.o, $(libs-y))

u-boot-init := $(head-y)
u-boot-main := $(libs-y)


# Add GCC lib
ifeq ($(CONFIG_USE_PRIVATE_LIBGCC),y)
PLATFORM_LIBGCC = arch/$(ARCH)/lib/lib.a
else
PLATFORM_LIBGCC := -L $(shell dirname `$(CC) $(c_flags) -print-libgcc-file-name`) -lgcc
endif
PLATFORM_LIBS += $(PLATFORM_LIBGCC)
export PLATFORM_LIBS
export PLATFORM_LIBGCC

# Special flags for CPP when processing the linker script.
# Pass the version down so we can handle backwards compatibility
# on the fly.
LDPPFLAGS += \
    -include $(srctree)/include/u-boot/u-boot.lds.h \
    -DCPUDIR=$(CPUDIR) \
    $(shell $(LD) --version | \
      sed -ne 's/GNU ld version \([0-9][0-9]*\)\.\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/-DLD_MAJOR=\1 -DLD_MINOR=\2/p')


cmd_mkimage = $(objtree)/tools/mkimage $(MKIMAGEFLAGS_$(@F)) -d $< $@ \
    $(if $(KBUILD_VERBOSE:1=), >$(MKIMAGEOUTPUT))

quiet_cmd_mkfitimage = MKIMAGE $@
cmd_mkfitimage = $(objtree)/tools/mkimage $(MKIMAGEFLAGS_$(@F)) -f $(U_BOOT_ITS) -E $@ \
    $(if $(KBUILD_VERBOSE:1=), >$(MKIMAGEOUTPUT))

quiet_cmd_cat = CAT     $@
cmd_cat = cat $(filter-out $(PHONY), $^) > $@

append = cat $(filter-out $< $(PHONY), $^) >> $@

quiet_cmd_pad_cat = CAT     $@
cmd_pad_cat = $(cmd_objcopy) && $(append) || rm -f $@

cfg: u-boot.cfg

quiet_cmd_cfgcheck = CFGCHK  $2
cmd_cfgcheck = $(srctree)/scripts/check-config.sh $2 \
        $(srctree)/scripts/config_whitelist.txt $(srctree)

PHONY += dtbs
dtbs: dts/dt.dtb
    @:
dts/dt.dtb: u-boot
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=dts dtbs

quiet_cmd_copy = COPY    $@
      cmd_copy = cp $< $@

ifeq ($(CONFIG_MULTI_DTB_FIT),y)

fit-dtb.blob: dts/dt.dtb FORCE
    $(call if_changed,mkimage)

MKIMAGEFLAGS_fit-dtb.blob = -f auto -A $(ARCH) -T firmware -C none -O u-boot \
    -a 0 -e 0 -E \
    $(patsubst %,-b arch/$(ARCH)/dts/%.dtb,$(subst ",,$(CONFIG_OF_LIST))) -d /dev/null

u-boot-fit-dtb.bin: u-boot-nodtb.bin fit-dtb.blob
    $(call if_changed,cat)

u-boot.bin: u-boot-fit-dtb.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,copy)
else ifeq ($(CONFIG_OF_SEPARATE),y)
u-boot-dtb.bin: u-boot-nodtb.bin dts/dt.dtb FORCE
    $(call if_changed,cat)

u-boot.bin: u-boot-dtb.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,copy)
else
u-boot.bin: u-boot-nodtb.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,copy)
endif

%.imx: %.bin
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=arch/arm/mach-imx $@

%.vyb: %.imx
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=arch/arm/cpu/armv7/vf610 $@

quiet_cmd_copy = COPY    $@
      cmd_copy = cp $< $@

u-boot.dtb: dts/dt.dtb
    $(call cmd,copy)

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot.hex := -O ihex

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot.srec := -O srec

u-boot.hex u-boot.srec: u-boot FORCE
    $(call if_changed,objcopy)

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot-elf.srec := $(OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot.srec)

u-boot-elf.srec: u-boot.elf FORCE
    $(call if_changed,objcopy)

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot-spl.srec = $(OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot.srec)

spl/u-boot-spl.srec: spl/u-boot-spl FORCE
    $(call if_changed,objcopy)

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot-nodtb.bin := -O binary \
        $(if $(CONFIG_X86_16BIT_INIT),-R .start16 -R .resetvec)


u-boot-nodtb.bin: u-boot FORCE
    $(call if_changed,objcopy)
    $(call DO_STATIC_RELA,$<,$@,$(CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE))
    $(BOARD_SIZE_CHECK)

u-boot.ldr: u-boot
        $(CREATE_LDR_ENV)
        $(LDR) -T $(CONFIG_CPU) -c $@ $< $(LDR_FLAGS)
        $(BOARD_SIZE_CHECK)

# binman
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
quiet_cmd_binman = BINMAN  $@
cmd_binman = $(srctree)/tools/binman/binman -d u-boot.dtb -O . \
        -I . -I $(srctree)/board/$(BOARDDIR) $<

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot.ldr.hex := -I binary -O ihex

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot.ldr.srec := -I binary -O srec

u-boot.ldr.hex u-boot.ldr.srec: u-boot.ldr FORCE
    $(call if_changed,objcopy)

#
# U-Boot entry point, needed for booting of full-blown U-Boot
# from the SPL U-Boot version.
#
ifndef CONFIG_SYS_UBOOT_START
CONFIG_SYS_UBOOT_START := 0
endif

# Create a file containing the configuration options the image was built with
quiet_cmd_cpp_cfg = CFG     $@
cmd_cpp_cfg = $(CPP) -Wp,-MD,$(depfile) $(cpp_flags) $(LDPPFLAGS) -ansi \
    -DDO_DEPS_ONLY -D__ASSEMBLY__ -x assembler-with-cpp -P -dM -E -o $@ $<

MKIMAGEFLAGS_u-boot-dtb.img = $(MKIMAGEFLAGS_u-boot.img)

MKIMAGEFLAGS_u-boot.kwb = -n $(srctree)/$(CONFIG_SYS_KWD_CONFIG:"%"=%) \
    -T kwbimage -a $(CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE) -e $(CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE)

MKIMAGEFLAGS_u-boot-spl.kwb = -n $(srctree)/$(CONFIG_SYS_KWD_CONFIG:"%"=%) \
    -T kwbimage -a $(CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE) -e $(CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE) \
    $(if $(KEYDIR),-k $(KEYDIR))

MKIMAGEFLAGS_u-boot.pbl = -n $(srctree)/$(CONFIG_SYS_FSL_PBL_RCW:"%"=%) \
        -R $(srctree)/$(CONFIG_SYS_FSL_PBL_PBI:"%"=%) -T pblimage

u-boot-dtb.img u-boot.img u-boot.kwb u-boot.pbl u-boot-ivt.img: \
        $(if $(CONFIG_SPL_LOAD_FIT),u-boot-nodtb.bin dts/dt.dtb,u-boot.bin) FORCE
    $(call if_changed,mkimage)

u-boot.itb: u-boot-nodtb.bin dts/dt.dtb $(U_BOOT_ITS) FORCE
    $(call if_changed,mkfitimage)
    $(BOARD_SIZE_CHECK)

u-boot-spl.kwb: u-boot.img spl/u-boot-spl.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,mkimage)

u-boot.sha1:    u-boot.bin
        tools/ubsha1 u-boot.bin

u-boot.dis: u-boot
        $(OBJDUMP) -d $< > $@

ifdef CONFIG_TPL
SPL_PAYLOAD := tpl/u-boot-with-tpl.bin
else
SPL_PAYLOAD := u-boot.bin
endif

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot-with-spl.bin = -I binary -O binary \
                   --pad-to=$(CONFIG_SPL_PAD_TO)
u-boot-with-spl.bin: spl/u-boot-spl.bin $(SPL_PAYLOAD) FORCE
    $(call if_changed,pad_cat)

MKIMAGEFLAGS_lpc32xx-spl.img = -T lpc32xximage -a $(CONFIG_SPL_TEXT_BASE)

lpc32xx-spl.img: spl/u-boot-spl.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,mkimage)

OBJCOPYFLAGS_lpc32xx-boot-0.bin = -I binary -O binary --pad-to=$(CONFIG_SPL_PAD_TO)

lpc32xx-boot-0.bin: lpc32xx-spl.img FORCE
    $(call if_changed,objcopy)

OBJCOPYFLAGS_lpc32xx-boot-1.bin = -I binary -O binary --pad-to=$(CONFIG_SPL_PAD_TO)

lpc32xx-boot-1.bin: lpc32xx-spl.img FORCE
    $(call if_changed,objcopy)

lpc32xx-full.bin: lpc32xx-boot-0.bin lpc32xx-boot-1.bin u-boot.img FORCE
    $(call if_changed,cat)

CLEAN_FILES += lpc32xx-*

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot-with-tpl.bin = -I binary -O binary \
                   --pad-to=$(CONFIG_TPL_PAD_TO)
tpl/u-boot-with-tpl.bin: tpl/u-boot-tpl.bin u-boot.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,pad_cat)

SPL: spl/u-boot-spl.bin FORCE
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=arch/arm/mach-imx $@

u-boot-with-spl.imx u-boot-with-nand-spl.imx: SPL u-boot.bin FORCE
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=arch/arm/mach-imx $@

MKIMAGEFLAGS_u-boot.ubl = -n $(UBL_CONFIG) -T ublimage -e $(CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE)

u-boot.ubl: u-boot-with-spl.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,mkimage)

MKIMAGEFLAGS_u-boot-spl.ais = -s -n $(if $(CONFIG_AIS_CONFIG_FILE), \
    $(srctree)/$(CONFIG_AIS_CONFIG_FILE:"%"=%),"/dev/null") \
    -T aisimage -e $(CONFIG_SPL_TEXT_BASE)
spl/u-boot-spl.ais: spl/u-boot-spl.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,mkimage)

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot.ais = -I binary -O binary --pad-to=$(CONFIG_SPL_PAD_TO)
u-boot.ais: spl/u-boot-spl.ais u-boot.img FORCE
    $(call if_changed,pad_cat)

u-boot-signed.sb: u-boot.bin spl/u-boot-spl.bin
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=arch/arm/cpu/arm926ejs/mxs u-boot-signed.sb
u-boot.sb: u-boot.bin spl/u-boot-spl.bin
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=arch/arm/cpu/arm926ejs/mxs u-boot.sb

# On x600 (SPEAr600) U-Boot is appended to U-Boot SPL.
# Both images are created using mkimage (crc etc), so that the ROM
# bootloader can check its integrity. Padding needs to be done to the
# SPL image (with mkimage header) and not the binary. Otherwise the resulting image
# which is loaded/copied by the ROM bootloader to SRAM doesn't fit.
# The resulting image containing both U-Boot images is called u-boot.spr
MKIMAGEFLAGS_u-boot-spl.img = -A $(ARCH) -T firmware -C none \
    -a $(CONFIG_SPL_TEXT_BASE) -e $(CONFIG_SPL_TEXT_BASE) -n XLOADER
spl/u-boot-spl.img: spl/u-boot-spl.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,mkimage)

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot.spr = -I binary -O binary --pad-to=$(CONFIG_SPL_PAD_TO) \
              --gap-fill=0xff
u-boot.spr: spl/u-boot-spl.img u-boot.img FORCE
    $(call if_changed,pad_cat)

ifneq ($(CONFIG_ARCH_SOCFPGA),)
quiet_cmd_socboot = SOCBOOT $@
cmd_socboot = cat   spl/u-boot-spl.sfp spl/u-boot-spl.sfp   \
            spl/u-boot-spl.sfp spl/u-boot-spl.sfp   \
            u-boot.img > $@ || rm -f $@
u-boot-with-spl.sfp: spl/u-boot-spl.sfp u-boot.img FORCE
    $(call if_changed,socboot)
endif

# x86 uses a large ROM. We fill it with 0xff, put the 16-bit stuff (including
# reset vector) at the top, Intel ME descriptor at the bottom, and U-Boot in
# the middle. This is handled by binman based on an image description in the
# board's device tree.
ifneq ($(CONFIG_X86_RESET_VECTOR),)
rom: u-boot.rom FORCE

refcode.bin: $(srctree)/board/$(BOARDDIR)/refcode.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,copy)

quiet_cmd_ldr = LD      $@
cmd_ldr = $(LD) $(LDFLAGS_$(@F)) \
           $(filter-out FORCE,$^) -o $@

u-boot.rom: u-boot-x86-16bit.bin u-boot.bin \
        $(if $(CONFIG_SPL_X86_16BIT_INIT),spl/u-boot-spl.bin) \
        $(if $(CONFIG_HAVE_REFCODE),refcode.bin) FORCE
    $(call if_changed,binman)

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot-x86-16bit.bin := -O binary -j .start16 -j .resetvec
u-boot-x86-16bit.bin: u-boot FORCE
    $(call if_changed,objcopy)
endif

ifneq ($(CONFIG_ARCH_SUNXI),)
u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin: spl/sunxi-spl.bin u-boot.img u-boot.dtb FORCE
    $(call if_changed,binman)
endif

ifneq ($(CONFIG_TEGRA),)
ifneq ($(CONFIG_BINMAN),)
u-boot-dtb-tegra.bin u-boot-tegra.bin u-boot-nodtb-tegra.bin: \
        spl/u-boot-spl u-boot.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,binman)
else
OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot-nodtb-tegra.bin = -O binary --pad-to=$(CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE)
u-boot-nodtb-tegra.bin: spl/u-boot-spl u-boot-nodtb.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,pad_cat)

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot-tegra.bin = -O binary --pad-to=$(CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE)
u-boot-tegra.bin: spl/u-boot-spl u-boot.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,pad_cat)

u-boot-dtb-tegra.bin: u-boot-tegra.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,copy)
endif  # binman
endif

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot-app.efi := $(OBJCOPYFLAGS_EFI)
u-boot-app.efi: u-boot FORCE
    $(call if_changed,zobjcopy)

u-boot.bin.o: u-boot.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,efipayload)

u-boot-payload.lds: $(LDSCRIPT_EFI) FORCE
    $(call if_changed_dep,cpp_lds)

# Rule to link the EFI payload which contains a stub and a U-Boot binary
quiet_cmd_u-boot_payload ?= LD      $@
      cmd_u-boot_payload ?= $(LD) $(LDFLAGS_EFI_PAYLOAD) -o $@ \
      -T u-boot-payload.lds arch/x86/cpu/call32.o \
      lib/efi/efi.o lib/efi/efi_stub.o u-boot.bin.o \
      $(addprefix arch/$(ARCH)/lib/,$(EFISTUB))

u-boot-payload: u-boot.bin.o u-boot-payload.lds FORCE
    $(call if_changed,u-boot_payload)

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot-payload.efi := $(OBJCOPYFLAGS_EFI)
u-boot-payload.efi: u-boot-payload FORCE
    $(call if_changed,zobjcopy)

u-boot-img.bin: spl/u-boot-spl.bin u-boot.img FORCE
    $(call if_changed,cat)

#Add a target to create boot binary having SPL binary in PBI format
#concatenated with u-boot binary. It is need by PowerPC SoC having
#internal SRAM <= 512KB.
MKIMAGEFLAGS_u-boot-spl.pbl = -n $(srctree)/$(CONFIG_SYS_FSL_PBL_RCW:"%"=%) \
        -R $(srctree)/$(CONFIG_SYS_FSL_PBL_PBI:"%"=%) -T pblimage \
        -A $(ARCH) -a $(CONFIG_SPL_TEXT_BASE)

spl/u-boot-spl.pbl: spl/u-boot-spl.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,mkimage)

ifeq ($(ARCH),arm)
UBOOT_BINLOAD := u-boot.img
else
UBOOT_BINLOAD := u-boot.bin
endif

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot-with-spl-pbl.bin = -I binary -O binary --pad-to=$(CONFIG_SPL_PAD_TO) \
              --gap-fill=0xff

u-boot-with-spl-pbl.bin: spl/u-boot-spl.pbl $(UBOOT_BINLOAD) FORCE
    $(call if_changed,pad_cat)

# PPC4xx needs the SPL at the end of the image, since the reset vector
# is located at 0xfffffffc. So we can't use the "u-boot-img.bin" target
# and need to introduce a new build target with the full blown U-Boot
# at the start padded up to the start of the SPL image. And then concat
# the SPL image to the end.

OBJCOPYFLAGS_u-boot-img-spl-at-end.bin := -I binary -O binary \
    --pad-to=$(CONFIG_UBOOT_PAD_TO) --gap-fill=0xff
u-boot-img-spl-at-end.bin: u-boot.img spl/u-boot-spl.bin FORCE
    $(call if_changed,pad_cat)

# Create a new ELF from a raw binary file.
ifndef PLATFORM_ELFENTRY
  PLATFORM_ELFENTRY = "_start"
endif
quiet_cmd_u-boot-elf ?= LD      $@
    cmd_u-boot-elf ?= $(LD) u-boot-elf.o -o $@ \
    --defsym=$(PLATFORM_ELFENTRY)=$(CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE) \
    -Ttext=$(CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE)
u-boot.elf: u-boot.bin
    $(Q)$(OBJCOPY) -I binary $(PLATFORM_ELFFLAGS) $< u-boot-elf.o
    $(call if_changed,u-boot-elf)

ARCH_POSTLINK := $(wildcard $(srctree)/arch/$(ARCH)/Makefile.postlink)

# Rule to link u-boot
# May be overridden by arch/$(ARCH)/config.mk
quiet_cmd_u-boot__ ?= LD      $@
      cmd_u-boot__ ?= $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS_u-boot) -o $@ \
      -T u-boot.lds $(u-boot-init)                             \
      --start-group $(u-boot-main) --end-group                 \
      $(PLATFORM_LIBS) -Map u-boot.map;                        \
      $(if $(ARCH_POSTLINK), $(MAKE) -f $(ARCH_POSTLINK) $@, true)

quiet_cmd_smap = GEN     common/system_map.o
cmd_smap = \
    smap=`$(call SYSTEM_MAP,u-boot) | \
        awk '$$2 ~ /[tTwW]/ {printf $$1 $$3 "\\\\000"}'` ; \
    $(CC) $(c_flags) -DSYSTEM_MAP="\"$${smap}\"" \
        -c $(srctree)/common/system_map.c -o common/system_map.o

u-boot: $(u-boot-init) $(u-boot-main) u-boot.lds FORCE
    +$(call if_changed,u-boot__)
ifeq ($(CONFIG_KALLSYMS),y)
    $(call cmd,smap)
    $(call cmd,u-boot__) common/system_map.o
endif

ifeq ($(CONFIG_RISCV),y)
    @tools/prelink-riscv $@ 0
endif

quiet_cmd_sym ?= SYM     $@
      cmd_sym ?= $(OBJDUMP) -t $< > $@
u-boot.sym: u-boot FORCE
    $(call if_changed,sym)

# The actual objects are generated when descending,
# make sure no implicit rule kicks in
$(sort $(u-boot-init) $(u-boot-main)): $(u-boot-dirs) ;

# Handle descending into subdirectories listed in $(vmlinux-dirs)
# Preset locale variables to speed up the build process. Limit locale
# tweaks to this spot to avoid wrong language settings when running
# make menuconfig etc.
# Error messages still appears in the original language

PHONY += $(u-boot-dirs)
$(u-boot-dirs): prepare scripts
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=$@

tools: prepare
# The "tools" are needed early
$(filter-out tools, $(u-boot-dirs)): tools
# The "examples" conditionally depend on U-Boot (say, when USE_PRIVATE_LIBGCC
# is "yes"), so compile examples after U-Boot is compiled.
examples: $(filter-out examples, $(u-boot-dirs))

define filechk_uboot.release
    echo "$(UBOOTVERSION)$$($(CONFIG_SHELL) $(srctree)/scripts/setlocalversion $(srctree))"
endef

# Store (new) UBOOTRELEASE string in include/config/uboot.release
include/config/uboot.release: include/config/auto.conf FORCE
    $(call filechk,uboot.release)


# Things we need to do before we recursively start building the kernel
# or the modules are listed in "prepare".
# A multi level approach is used. prepareN is processed before prepareN-1.
# archprepare is used in arch Makefiles and when processed asm symlink,
# version.h and scripts_basic is processed / created.

# Listed in dependency order
PHONY += prepare archprepare prepare0 prepare1 prepare2 prepare3

# prepare3 is used to check if we are building in a separate output directory,
# and if so do:
# 1) Check that make has not been executed in the kernel src $(srctree)
prepare3: include/config/uboot.release
ifneq ($(KBUILD_SRC),)
    @$(kecho) '  Using $(srctree) as source for U-Boot'
    $(Q)if [ -f $(srctree)/.config -o -d $(srctree)/include/config ]; then \
        echo >&2 "  $(srctree) is not clean, please run 'make mrproper'"; \
        echo >&2 "  in the '$(srctree)' directory.";\
        /bin/false; \
    fi;
endif

# prepare2 creates a makefile if using a separate output directory
prepare2: prepare3 outputmakefile

prepare1: prepare2 $(version_h) $(timestamp_h) \
                   include/config/auto.conf
ifeq ($(wildcard $(LDSCRIPT)),)
    @echo >&2 "  Could not find linker script."
    @/bin/false
endif

archprepare: prepare1 scripts_basic

prepare0: archprepare FORCE
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=.

# All the preparing..
prepare: prepare0

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
quiet_cmd_cpp_lds = LDS     $@
cmd_cpp_lds = $(CPP) -Wp,-MD,$(depfile) $(cpp_flags) $(LDPPFLAGS) \
        -D__ASSEMBLY__ -x assembler-with-cpp -P -o $@ $<

u-boot.lds: $(LDSCRIPT) prepare FORCE
    $(call if_changed_dep,cpp_lds)

spl/u-boot-spl.bin: spl/u-boot-spl
    @:
spl/u-boot-spl: tools prepare \
        $(if $(CONFIG_OF_SEPARATE)$(CONFIG_OF_EMBED)$(CONFIG_SPL_OF_PLATDATA),dts/dt.dtb) \
        $(if $(CONFIG_OF_SEPARATE)$(CONFIG_OF_EMBED)$(CONFIG_TPL_OF_PLATDATA),dts/dt.dtb)
    $(Q)$(MAKE) obj=spl -f $(srctree)/scripts/Makefile.spl all

spl/sunxi-spl.bin: spl/u-boot-spl
    @:

spl/sunxi-spl-with-ecc.bin: spl/sunxi-spl.bin
    @:

spl/u-boot-spl.sfp: spl/u-boot-spl
    @:

spl/boot.bin: spl/u-boot-spl
    @:

tpl/u-boot-tpl.bin: tools prepare \
        $(if $(CONFIG_OF_SEPARATE)$(CONFIG_OF_EMBED)$(CONFIG_SPL_OF_PLATDATA),dts/dt.dtb)
    $(Q)$(MAKE) obj=tpl -f $(srctree)/scripts/Makefile.spl all

TAG_SUBDIRS := $(patsubst %,$(srctree)/%,$(u-boot-dirs) include)

FIND := find
FINDFLAGS := -L

tags ctags:
        ctags -w -o ctags `$(FIND) $(FINDFLAGS) $(TAG_SUBDIRS) \
                        -name '*.[chS]' -print`
        ln -s ctags tags

etags:
        etags -a -o etags `$(FIND) $(FINDFLAGS) $(TAG_SUBDIRS) \
                        -name '*.[chS]' -print`
cscope:
        $(FIND) $(FINDFLAGS) $(TAG_SUBDIRS) -name '*.[chS]' -print > \
                        cscope.files
        cscope -b -q -k

SYSTEM_MAP = \
        $(NM) $1 | \
        grep -v '\(compiled\)\|\(\.o$$\)\|\( [aUw] \)\|\(\.\.ng$$\)\|\(LASH[RL]DI\)' | \
        LC_ALL=C sort
System.map: u-boot
        @$(call SYSTEM_MAP,$<) > $@

# Documentation targets
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%docs: scripts_basic FORCE
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=scripts build_docproc
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=doc/DocBook $@

endif #ifeq ($(config-targets),1)
endif #ifeq ($(mixed-targets),1)

PHONY += checkstack ubootrelease ubootversion

checkstack:
    $(OBJDUMP) -d u-boot $$(find . -name u-boot-spl) | \
    $(PERL) $(src)/scripts/checkstack.pl $(ARCH)

ubootrelease:
    @echo "$(UBOOTVERSION)$$($(CONFIG_SHELL) $(srctree)/scripts/setlocalversion $(srctree))"

ubootversion:
    @echo $(UBOOTVERSION)

# Single targets
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Single targets are compatible with:
# - build with mixed source and output
# - build with separate output dir 'make O=...'
# - external modules
#
#  target-dir => where to store outputfile
#  build-dir  => directory in kernel source tree to use

ifeq ($(KBUILD_EXTMOD),)
        build-dir  = $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $@))
        target-dir = $(dir $@)
else
        zap-slash=$(filter-out .,$(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $@)))
        build-dir  = $(KBUILD_EXTMOD)$(if $(zap-slash),/$(zap-slash))
        target-dir = $(if $(KBUILD_EXTMOD),$(dir $<),$(dir $@))
endif

%.s: %.c prepare scripts FORCE
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=$(build-dir) $(target-dir)$(notdir $@)
%.i: %.c prepare scripts FORCE
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=$(build-dir) $(target-dir)$(notdir $@)
%.o: %.c prepare scripts FORCE
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=$(build-dir) $(target-dir)$(notdir $@)
%.lst: %.c prepare scripts FORCE
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=$(build-dir) $(target-dir)$(notdir $@)
%.s: %.S prepare scripts FORCE
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=$(build-dir) $(target-dir)$(notdir $@)
%.o: %.S prepare scripts FORCE
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=$(build-dir) $(target-dir)$(notdir $@)
%.symtypes: %.c prepare scripts FORCE
    $(Q)$(MAKE) $(build)=$(build-dir) $(target-dir)$(notdir $@)
```

Comment: The above Makefile looks similar to that of a Kernel Source tree. Are you trying to compile a Linux Kernel driver?

Comment: If there are no files from which the object file can be created by implicit rules, but the   Makefile references the object file in the link command line, there'll be no problem.  If the object file vanishes, then compilations will fail.  If there are source files from which the object file can be created, they will be used if the object file is older than the corresponding source files.

Comment: If you literally have `CONFIG_xxx`, it is likely to make no sense. What is the actual config you are trying to link?

Comment: @Gaurav  yes, I made some function for Linux kernel driver to invoke

Comment: @user58697 I have defined CONFIG_xxx in KCONFIG.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is there any guide for adding reference the obj file in the link command line ?

Comment: It depends how your makefile is written.  If you have a rule like `program: ${OBJECTS}` —— `${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${OBJECTS} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}` then you simply make sure your object file is listed in `${OBJECTS}`.  That might be `OBJECTS += your_object.o`.  If you have something more complex, then the change is correspondingly more complex.

Comment: Your question doesn't show your makefile — or, if that ___is___ your makefile, it is like no other makefile I've ever seen, and it must be leveraging a huge framework that gives meaning to names like `obj-${CONFIG_SH_MMCIF}`.   The indentation is suspect — are those lines indented in the makefile?  If those are all macros — and it looks like they are — then there must be some code somewhere, probably in an included file, that makes use of them.  Look for `include` lines in the makefile(s), or maybe you invoke `make -f template.1 -f makefile -f template.2` or some other fancy mechanism.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Just for confirmation, does compile check source file if I write OBJECTS += your_object.o ?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you write `your_object.o` into the `makefile`; when it comes time to use it, if it is listed as a dependency, then it will be checked to see whether it needs to be rebuilt.  If it is not listed as a dependency (it just appears magically in a command line), it will not be checked.  It all hinges on how your makefile is written.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have already put parts of the Makefile in root folder. Even if I find the TARGET or proper position to do modification. I still don't know how to achieve my need.